# Build and Release Menu Missing in TFS2015

Tags: xaml, build, msbuild, release, tfs-2015

We have installed TFS2015 and trying to use the Build and Release functionality.

We got a session from Microsoft , and the administration console of the guy who gave the session got "**Build and Release**" Menu.

When we tried to install TFS2015 we were not able to see the menu. We can see only XAML Build Configuration under "Additional Tools and Components". Should i install anything else to view the "Build and Release" menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build and Release menu is exists in TFS 2015 Update 2 and upper version on TFS administration console. If you just install TFS 2015 RTM, you can't see it. Please update TFS to [TFS 2015 Update 2/3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update3-vs) and check again. Make sure you didn't install a TFS Express version.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the information. Will try and let you know!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hi Sorry,still waiting to get the update from the management to install. Is it possible to download the update from administration console?

Comment: @Nikitha what do you mean download from admin console. You just download the installation package by clicking the link I posted above. And install it on your TFS server. Then after installation finishes, choose Upgrade.

Comment: Hi yes it is showing the menu now after upgrade. Thanks a lot for the help!.